# When using Storyboards, why does viewWillAppear not draw my subviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews does

Tags: ios, objective-c

When using Storyboards, why does **`viewWillAppear`** not draw my subviews and **`viewDidLayoutSubviews`** does and more importantly to access the **`frame.size`** value from subviews of subviews I have to call **`[self.scroller layoutIfNeeded]`** inside of **`viewDidLayoutSubviews`**? I'm interested in understanding the page life cycle of a view controller and what changed in going from xibs to storyboards.

[image: screenshot of view hierarchy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards are actually implemented as collections of xib files, with additional information about transitions (segues) between them. So the view controller life cycle should not be radically different if we're just talking about a single view controller.

It's very difficult to answer your specific question without understanding how your view controller and its view hierarchy are set up. It sounds like you have a view inside of a scroll view and you want to know when you can access its `frame` property.

UIKit follows these steps (roughly):

1. It loads all the views described in the storyboard/xib file and connects all the actions and outlets as needed. `viewDidLoad` is called after this step.
2. It calls `viewWillAppear:` to indicate that it is about to display the view.
3. It adds the view to the window, sizing it to fit. The sizing propagates down the view hierarchy, so each view lays out its subviews (if it is configured to autoresize subviews). These changes occur inside an animation block, so once everything is set up the user sees the new view animated into place.
4. Once animations are complete, `viewDidAppear:` is called.

It's possible you are seeing something strange if a view has `autoresizesSubviews` set to `NO`; that may be why you have to call `layoutIfNeeded` on `self.scroller`. Note that the documentation for `layoutIfNeeded` says:

> When this message is received, the layer’s super layers are traversed until a ancestor layer is found that does not require layout. Then layout is performed on the entire layer-tree beneath that ancestor.

So it could potentially be triggering the layout of other unrelated views.

Comment: I was trying to get the "frame.size" property in and it didn't show it in the viewDidLoad either. Also, I was able to get the frame.size property in the viewWillAppear when I built my xib in IB, but for some reason with storyboards that's not the case. I guess what I'm getting at is I would like more meat to your answer.

Comment: @Benny Updated. Honestly, your question is kind of unclear, I did the best I could.

Comment: Good stuff thanks for giving more detail! I do have autoresize Subviews selected in IB. Let me attach some screenshots

Comment: ALSO, where does viewDidLayoutSubviews fit into the cycle?

Comment: @Benny After #3 in my list, when the view is resized; when a view's size changes it lays out its subviews (assuming its `autoresizesSubviews` property is set)